# LD_LIBRARY_PATH won't work with more than one path

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, shared-libraries

I am trying to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH in my .bashrc, but it wont work when I add more than one path:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/lib1
```

works fine, and when I type $LD_LIBRARY_PATH on a new terminal, I get

```
$ $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
bash: /path/to/lib1: is a directory
```

but when I try

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/lib1:/path/to/lib2 
(I also tried export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/lib2:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
```

I get

```
$ $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
bash: /path/to/lib1:/path/to/lib2: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas why this may be happening?

Comment: Try `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  What are you expecting it to do when you just type it at the command line?

Comment: `bash: /path/to/lib1: is a directory` is an error message too. It's short for "Can't execute /path/to/lib1 because it is a directory"

Comment: Both the commands yield an error message, since you're trying to run the value stored in the $LD_LIBRARY_PATH as a command. Instead you should be using echo to print the value of $LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: Thanks guys. Just realized that this was a really bad case of brain fart, and was a very stupid question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you would like to check the value of $LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

use

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Otherwise bash would thought you asked it to execute a command stored in $LD_LIBRARY_PATH.